# Access Handler object to Rollover log

Tags: python, logging

How can I rollover my log when I've setup my log using `logging.config.dictConfig`? I can't retrieve my `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`.

```
import logging 
import logging.config


logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "filename": "test.log",
            'backupCount': 5,
            'maxBytes': 20,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
})

# How do I do rollover??
logging.handler[0].doRollover()

logging.info("foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the root handlers using `logging.getLogger().handlers`, so if you have just one  you might do something like

```
for h in logging.getLogger().handlers:
    if type(h) == logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler:
        h.doRollover()
```